# Как рассчитывать маску подсети?

Tags: подсети, маска

Рассчитать маску подсети, включающей адреса `10.61.11.1`, `10.61.10.1`, и не включающей адрес 10.61.8.1

Рассчитать маску подсети, включающей адрес `10.61.11.160`, и не включающей адреса `10.61.11.172`, `10.61.11.128`.

Comment: Раскидываешь адреса на биты, пишешь один под другим - и ответ становится очевидным.

Comment: Попробуйте разобраться, что такое маска подсети, используя данное наглядное руководство:
https://www.net4me.net/old/info/net_protocol_ip_route/mask_ipv4_adress_howto/

Answer (score 1):

Маска подсети при наложении (логическим И) на ip выделяет часть адреса, одинаковую у всех адресов в данной подсети. Для ее поиска необходимо записать в двоичном виде ip адреса и найти самый старший бит, который отличается у  адресов. IP адреса (версии ipv4) состоят из 4х байт. При записи их десятичные значения разделяются точкой. Самый старший байт записан первым. Поэтому, для начала найдем сходство на уровне байтов. Те байты, которые, начиная со старшего, одинаковы, нас не интересуют, маска на их месте содержит все 1 биты, т.е. имеет значение 255. Рассмотрим в битовом виде тот байт, который отличается и найдем самый старший бит в нем, который отличается. все что левее него - в маске 1, он сам и все, что правее - нули.

Например 10.61.11.1, 10.61.10.1, 10.61.10.1. У всех трех адресов старшие два байта равны. 10.61. Значит их мы не рассматриваем, а на их месте в маске пишем 255.255. Третий байт отличается, расписываем его побитно (для быстрого перевода удобно использовать калькулятор windows в режиме "программист"):

```
11:  0000 1011
10:  0000 1010
 8:  0000 1000
```

Видим, что у первых двух чисел отличается только самый младший бит. Все биты, которые равны (слева на право, до первого отличающегося) выставляем в 1, остальные делаем 0

```
10:11: 1111 1110
10:8 : 1111 1100
```

В общем то тут сразу видно чем отличается маска включающая только 10 и 11 от 8. Остается записать адрес самой сети, это биты адресов, которые общие, остальные нули. Собственно биты числа 10 и являются тем минимальным числом, которое в нашем случае обозначает сеть. Значит наша сеть 10.61.10.0, а маска подсети `255.255.(11111110).0 = 255.255.254.0`. Если нужна маска в виде количества бит, как часто принято записывать, считаем единичные биты всех байт слева на право: 8+8+7=23, значит точный адрес сети: 10.61.10.0/23

На втором примере потренируйтесь сами (там первые 3 байта одинаковы, раскладываем на биты и изучаем четвертый)

Comment: Все понял, все найс